# Change of font size and Style

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, fonts

Am currently working on a task in aspnet mvc project using c#.
I aim at changing users input font Color and font style.
I.e once a user types in something in a TextArea or TextBox,  I want the program to Change the font to another font automatically.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have already tried and what specific issue you're having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input').on('change',function(){
  $('body').css('font-family',$('#font').val());
  $('body').css('font-size',$('#size').val()+'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="font" type="text" value="input font"/>
<input id="size" type="text" value="inpupt size"/>

<p>
Sample Text
</p>
```

```
<input id="font" type="text" value="input text font"/>
<input  id="size" type="text" value"input text size"/>
$('input').on('change',function(){
   var font = $('#font').val();
   var size = $('#size').val();
   $('body').css('font-size',size+'px');
   $('body').css('font-family',font);
});
```

Comment: as my senior would say go be happy :D live long and prosper xD

Comment: @AKINTOLA STEPHEN IYANU is your problem resovled if yes you can click the tick button to mark it  as answer]